# How to create interdependent columns in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to create is a budget spread sheet that can have values be entered into one cell of the daily, weekly, monthly, or yearly columns and it will calculate across the row what the others will be.

```
          A                   B                  C                   D                  E
1  CATEGORY        DAILY BUDGET      WEEKLY BUDGET      MONTHLY BUDGET      YEARLY BUDGET
2  Restaurants            $1.43            *$10.00*             $43.45            $521.43
3  Fuel                   $3.29             $23.01            *$100.00*         $1,200.00
4  Daily coffee          *$1.65*            $11.55              $50.19            $602.25
5  Auto Insurance         $3.29             $23.01             $100.00         *$1,200.00*
```

It would look like the above, where asterisks denote where the first-order value is entered. For example, $10 entered in the weekly budget column calculates the values across the other three, and so on for the remaining rows which have first-order values entered in each of the different columns.

I know enough that it involves some Excel VBA. In fact, this answer on [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091208202027AACC8rz) is very close to what I'd like to do except I need it to work with columns across the active cell's respective row.

EDIT: Added column and row references to my table and here is my code I've modified:

```
Private Sub PeriodConversion(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
    [C2] = [B2] * 7
    [E2] = [B2] * 365
    [D2] = [E2] / 12
ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
    [B2] = [C2] / 7
    [E2] = [B2] * 365
    [D2] = [E2] / 12
ElseIf Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
    [E2] = [D2] * 12
    [B2] = [E2] / 365
    [C2] = [B2] * 7
ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$2" Then
    [D2] = [E2] / 12
    [B2] = [E2] / 365
    [C2] = [B2] * 7
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Although it doesn't seem to be working.. :\

Comment: Who spends more coffee per day than food (restaurant)?

Comment: It all needs to be in the same table. Is it possible? I may not know how you mean by separating..

And @findwindow, the whole idea is to see prorates.. You'd actually only be going to the restaurant once (or twice if it's fast food) per week, hence why it is entered under the weekly budget interval.

Comment: @CalvinBroadus lol I was trolling because you didn't demonstrate any effort XD but pnuts seems happy to help ^_^

Comment: With @pnuts method you also need a trigger to know which is the `first order` period (or perhaps a lookup table that says coffee = daily, restaurant = weekly). It's a nice non-vba solution if you set up your spreadsheet just the right way.

Comment: Can the trigger be the active cell that has an entered value? The code I am wrestling with is the one posted on Yahoo Answers. Sorry, I am pretty much a newbie when it comes to VBA.

Comment: you don't need VBA at all if you place the `first order entry` cell in a separate column, then use formulas to calc the time period budget columns. If you **absolutely** have to have VBA, post the code you are working with (I am sure you are editing the code from the link) and where you are struggling, then we can help.

Comment: The trigger from the yahoo example is the last cell (or group of cells, if many cells were changed at once) to be changed.  This cell is referred to as "Target".  You could see what column "Target" is in (`Target.Column`) and based on that, change the Target's neighbors accordingly.  I would agree with some of the other comments, that you take a stab at it, and post your code and people will help get it closer to what you need.

Comment: @Demetri Kinda new so asking about community conventions: Is it best to try more, make a new one, and nuke this one; or keep adding to this one with my attempts?

Comment: I'm somewhat new myself, so I'm not sure exactly how to advise regarding conventions.  I'll be signing off for the weekend, but good luck and hope you find the solutions you need.

Comment: I would leave what you have, now that you have put your code it was easier to help you fix it, @Demetri answer will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this, but based on the idea you began, perhaps try this:

(Placing the code in the worksheet where the table is located)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row=1 then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 2
            '    [C2] = [B2] * 7
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value * 7
            '    [E2] = [B2] * 365
            Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = Target.Value * 365
            '    [D2] = [E2] / 12
            Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Offset(0, 3).Value / 12
        Case 3
            '    [B2] = [C2] / 7
            Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Value / 7
            '    [E2] = [B2] * 365
            Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value * 365
            '    [D2] = [E2] / 12
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Offset(0, 2).Value / 12
        Case 4
            '    [E2] = [D2] * 12
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value * 12
            '    [B2] = [E2] / 365
            Target.Offset(0, -2).Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value / 365
            '    [C2] = [B2] * 7
            Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Offset(0, -2).Value * 7
        Case 5
            '    [D2] = [E2] / 12
            Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Value / 12
            '    [B2] = [E2] / 365
            Target.Offset(0, -3).Value = Target.Value / 365
            '    [C2] = [B2] * 7
            Target.Offset(0, -2).Value = Target.Offset(0, -3).Value * 7
    End Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks. I've taken it further and added code that changed the fill color to the changed value and cleared the others, too. I learned a lot, thanks again!